# Discord Bot Not Receiving Interactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm a relatively experienced developer (graduated recently), trying to get back into discord bots after I made a few a couple of years ago.

I've been following the [guide on discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#resulting-code), but even with the basic "hello world" style program, I am already stuck.

**The program gives no errors when running, but no interactions come through in the console.**

- When I start the script, the bot switches to "online." Curiously, the bot does not switch back to "offline" until I regenerate the token. Not sure if that is related.
- I've verified `process.env.BOT_TOKEN` is the correct value.
- I've confirmed `client.login` runs successfully.
- I've tried DMing the bot directly
- I've tried sending messages on guild channels
- I've tried @ing the bot

Is there something super obvious I'm not understanding/seeing? Otherwise, what else should I try as a troubleshooting step?

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
    console.log(interaction);
});

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```

package.json:

```json
{
    "name": "timebot",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "start.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node -r dotenv/config start.js dotenv_config_path=secrets.env",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "discord.js": "^13.1.0",
        "dotenv": "^10.0.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out, messages are not classified as "interactions" by discord.js. Additionally, you have to specify the intent to listen for messages, otherwise, the event won't be passed to your bot. Here is the revised code with those two critical changes:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
    console.log(interaction);
});

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    console.log(message);
});

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```

Comment: I had to use this `const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, Discord.GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages] });`

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll add that I was using Discord.js v14.7.0 when this worked. I had been using an older version of Discord (v11) where the event was just called `message` instead of `messageCreate`. After I updated it to the right event for v14, I was receiving messages again